# How do you print the names of variables inside of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have made an array and placed some variables in it, and I want to get the name of the variable using the index number.

```
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;

var letters = [a,b,c]

console.log(letters)
```

I want to have it output "[ a, b, c ]" but this code actually outputs "[0, 0, 0]"

For more context, I plan to take the values of a, b, and c and then sort them based on their values, but then I still want to be able to see their variable names in the new order after they have been sorted.

Comment: Why are the variable names important to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object indexed by those variable names instead, and then you can take that object's `Object.keys`, which will give you an array of the properties:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj));
```

> I want to get the name of the variable using the index number.

Access that index in the `Object.keys` array, eg `Object.keys(obj)[1]` will evaluate to `b`.

To sort, take the `Object.entries` of the object (which will give you both the key and value at once):

```js
const obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
};
console.log(
  Object.entries(obj)
    .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but would I be able to sort the values as an object?

Comment: Sort the entries, and you'll get a sorted array of arrays, where the first item in the nested array is the key, and the second item is the value

Comment: @CertainPerformance - maybe slightly off topic but why use `const` here?

Comment: @billynoah as we are not mutating values of variable, so it's better to use `const`

Comment: @billynoah `const` is preferable to `var` because `const` has block scope and generally behaves much more intuitively, and `const` is preferable to `let` because `let` warns readers of the code that you may later reassign the variable, which requires slightly more cognitive overhead. `const` should be used by default for almost all variable declarations, at least in serious code (use Babel to transpile down to ES5 later, if needed)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a object instead, You can get keys as an array using `Object.keys` and later you sort them

```js
const obj = {
  a: 0,
  b: 2,
  c: 1
};
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

//sort keys based on values

const sorted = Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b)=> obj[a]-obj[b])

console.log(sorted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with an array - you'd have to use an object. You can get the keys with `Object.keys`, and the values with `Object.values`:

```js
var a = 0;
var b = 0;
var c = 0;
var letters = {a, b, c};

console.log(Object.keys(letters));
console.log(Object.values(letters));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score -1):

This might resolve your problem:

```js
var variableName = 0;
console.log(Object.keys({
  variableName
})[0]);
```